# Team site approval status pending

Tags: sharepoint-online

Team site is creating as regularly as I did before. But suddenly something happened and I'm waiting an approval and never getting back that notification. What can be a problem? Status of approval is pending. Even manually approved not working for me.

Comment: How and where did you create the team site? What's the permission of the account you use to create the site?Please provide some screenshots with us.

Comment: This weird that, only one user can't create team site. It provisioned on Azure. Other users haven't the same issue, but just one user can't create team site. What can be a problem?